# In Ember.js, how do you hook an object into a generic application namespace

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ember.js

Let's say I declared an application namespace:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
```

and later I write an arrayController instance that creates objects and hook it onto the app namespace on user event:

```
App.objController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],

    createObj: function(){
        // instantiate new object
        var newObj = Ember.Object.create({ ... })
        //give obj a name
        var newObjName = this._getObjName( someParam );
        // hook object to an app namespace -> this is where I have an issue
        App[newObjName] = newObj
   },

   ...

});
```

See I explicitly use App[newObjName] = newObj to hook the object onto the namespace, ideally I would like some sort of generic way to name the application namespace in case I use the objController for a different application later.

There has to be some way to do this though I am just not familiar enough with Ember to have encountered it.

Note: on a scale of 1 to JFGI, this question is definitely not a 1. On the other hand it's a free resolved checkmark for anyone that has a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the initialization phase, Ember will instantiate all of your controllers and inject three properties into each of them - "target", "controllers", "namespace". The "namespace" property is your application.

That said, instead of hard-coding the top-level object:

```
App[newObjName] = newObj
```

you can do the following:

```
this.get("namespace").set(newObjName, newObj);
```

Note - in order for this to work, your application needs a [router](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Router.html). Also, you should define controller classes, not instances. Ember will instantiate all controllers for you. So, this

```
App.objController = Ember.ArrayController.create({/* code here */});
```

should be written as

```
App.ObjController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({/* code here */});
```

Note the capital "O" in "ObjController".

Comment: So I put the this.get('namespace') command within a function in a controller class: App.ObjController extends Ember.ArrayController but it returned null? I then printed the class to console and poked around a bit, but could not find the property namespace...

Comment: @user1128571, Do you have a router in your app? You need to have one in order for injections to work

Comment: Ahh I see. Right now I am just developing bits of the app in isolation so that's why. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `injections`, which is the preferred way to add dependencies.

```
Ember.Application.registerInjection({
  name: 'fooObject',
  before: 'controllers',

  injection: function(app, router, property) {
    if (property === 'FooObject') {
      app.set('fooObject', app[property].create());
    }
  }
});
```

So if you define a class as follows:

```
App.FooObject = Ember.Object.extend({ 
  // ...
});
```

the injection will create an instance into `App.fooObject`. Although we still use the namespace `App`, however only once. You could further do:

```
Ember.FooObject = Ember.Object.extend({ 
  // ...
});
```

and then in your App, `App.FooObject = Ember.FooObject` but I'm not sure if its useful.

Comment: If OP wants to inject objects at runtime, this won't help